# Find out all of the platforms that are (non) mobile platforms with Flutter DeviceInfoPlugin

Tags: flutter, dart

For a study i created a Flutter Web App. Now i need to find out all of the (non) Flutter Platforms that use the web.
I use this method to check for platforms with [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus).
I need to make sure that only a non mobile browser can access a certain page.

```
Future<bool> checkForMobile() async {
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  var platform = (await deviceInfoPlugin.webBrowserInfo).platform!;
  if (equalsIgnoreCase(platform, "macOS") || equalsIgnoreCase(platform, "Win32")) {
    runApp(const NonMobilePage());
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And yes i know Flutter can be built for each individual platform, but for that study it has to be a Web Application